# Format of parent consent letter for applying for a Japanese visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, paperwork

I am an Indian student and am going to Japan for my summer internship this May. I wanted to know if there is any format for consent letter of parents. Does the letter needs to be from both the parents ? Also, what original documents should I produce to apply for VISA ?

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: I am 20. @jpatokal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're going for a summer internship, I'm assuming you're in college and thus above 18. You don't need a consent letter if you aren't a minor.

Coming to documents required, according to the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/index.html#section9) and [Visa Requirements for Indians- Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000121327.pdf) , you need

1. [Original letter of Invitation](http://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000137089.pdf) from the company or university that invited you

2.[Original Schedule of Stay](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/pdfs/application7.pdf)(Itinerary) signed by the person/company that invited you

3.[Certificate of guarantee](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/pdfs/application2.pdf) from company/University if they are covering your expenses

4.[An overview of company](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/pdfs/application6.pdf)/organization that is inviting you

5.[Filled Application form](http://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000124525.pdf)

6."Confirmation slip, certificate, or other documents to prove reservation of air or ship boarding ticket".

7. Certificate of Employment(However, since you're a student you'd need an NOC from the institute you're studying in.

8.Documents to prove ability to pay for travel expenses

- Travel requisition by employer
- Letter of mission
- Similar documents to above

Furthermore according to [Japan Embassy in India](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/short_term%20visas.html), you need

1. A document that shows tax returns/salary slip from your guarantor in Japan

If you don't have a guarantor in Japan and are either self-funded or funded by a national/state scholarship, you need to submit bank details/tax returns of the individual who is funding you and/or the details of the scholarship that will be covering your expenses

**Edit: I forgot to mention that you also need an NOC(No-Objection Letter) from your institute/university**

Comment: The checklist in the VFS website does ask for a consent letter but it doesn't specify that it is actually for minors. You can call and confirm the same

Comment: I applied for a Japan visa last month from the consulate in Kolkata successfully and no consent letter was required

Comment: Where are you going to be applying at? As in, what is your state of residence?

Comment: Can you share your experience like how much time did it take or what original documents you submitted ? Will the income tax return and bank statement documents need to be original or their scanned copy printout is okay ?

Comment: I applied in the Consulate-General of Japan at Kolkata as it is much cheaper and easier to apply at the Consulate rather than VFS. I only had to submit the Invitation letter, Schedule of stay and Certificate of Guarantee in original(Note that these documents need to be sent from your inviter in Japan). Apart from that I had to submit the flight tickets, and bank statements. It is advisable to ask your bank for original statements(or get printed statements signed at the bank). Photocopy of income tax returns is ok. It took 2 days and I got my passport after that

Comment: Very thanks for this info. I have the bank statement of last six months with the bank's seal. Do I need anything else to prove that the bank statement is valid ?

Comment: No, that much is enough

Comment: Are flight tickets necessary since I still haven't got them. Also, did you supply a bonafide letter/NOC from your institute ?

Comment: You can see on the embassy website(http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/short_term%20visas.html) that you need travel booking. Ideally your invitation letter and schedule of stay should also mention the date and airlines you're flying by and port of entry. 

I had missed mentioning the requirement of NOC, I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Very thanks for the answer Prathamesh. Just a last question, will a bonafide letter instead of an NOC suffice ?

Comment: I don't think so, you'd need a No-Objection letter, A bonafide letter just says that you're a bonafide a student of that institute

Comment: One more doubt, I only have my first name on passport and there is no surname on it, so what should I fill in the `surname` and `given name` fields in the Visa application form ?

Comment: Ignore the column then

Comment: Hi, @prathamesh, just one small doubt, excluding the passport first and last page photocopies, what other photocopies do I need ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a consent letter is required even if you are an adult because they have an option for consent from parents/spouse. If age was a factor they would not have mentioned spouse because only adults can be legally married to get consent from their spouse. And also one of my cousins who is married had to submit his spouse's consent to travel to Japan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).